# Kendo UI: Can I use a DataSource to sync data with standard HTML elements

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I am having trouble combining two kendo ideas that I have found individual examples for, but no combined example as of yet.

I have a page with simple HTML elements (textboxes, dropdowns, etc).  I have used this kendo example to link the view to a viewmodel.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/elements

Everything here works fine.  I can update the view, change values and see everything reflected in the viewmodel.

I have a remote service that is responsible for this data.  I followed this kendo example to create a DataSource for this remote.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/basic-usage

I have a read and update transport defined (as these are the only ones I need), and I have a schema defined for the data, with a valid id.  All of this works as well.  When I manually call read, the DataSource issues a read request to the service, and the data is returned.

I have seen plenty of examples of binding data sources to kendo grids, dropdowns, etc.  I cannot figure out how to bind the returned data from my data source to the elements from my page.

I can't even seem to hack something together by exploring with Chrome dev tools, though in the end I'd like more than a hack.  I'm hoping, whatever the solution may be, that it will scale for the entire site I'm working on.

What is the best way to do this?  I feel like I am misunderstanding something about how this is supposed to work.

Comment: can i see some of your code? are you trying to create grid or something ?

Comment: i have been trying to work up a code example.  i may have to wait until i am back at work on Monday.  i need to remove any company related bits, but i should be able to get an example up.

Comment: @machun to answer your question though: no.  i have a bunch of grid examples.  they work fine.  i need the results of a datasource read to fill my html elements rather than fill my grid rows.

Comment: A datasource is for array-like data, therefore it is useful for binding to grids, dropdowns, or even just an unordered list html tag. It sounds like you are asking how to use a datasource for binding to a variety of elements (inputs, spans, divs, etc) at once which isn't how they work. In your case, just use regular AJAX to retrieve your data and then bind it to the viewmodel.

Comment: @JFlox that's why i feel odd, except you just want to get the first/last/specific data from dataSource

Comment: @JFlox I had a feeling that was the answer.  Have any links to an example like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first link to kendo dojo ,inside the `viewModel` i create a function that contains ajax call to retrieve value from backend

```
getData: function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products", //replace this with your url to get the data from backend
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp" // replace this with the type suit your need maybe json or etc (just use this as example to fire the success event

}).success(function (data) {
    //asumme this dummy data is the data coming from backend
    var dummyData = {
        textValue: "new Text value",
        textareaValue: "new Textarea value",
        checkboxValue: true,
        radioValue: "new Apple",
        checkboxListValue: ["Banana"],
        multipleSelectValue: ["Banana"],
        fruits: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"],
        selectValue: "Orange"
    };
    //set the viewModel value with the data coming from backend
    viewModel.set("textValue", dummyData.textValue);
    viewModel.set("textareaValue", dummyData.textareaValue);
    viewModel.set("checkboxValue", dummyData.checkboxValue);
    viewModel.set("radioValue", dummyData.radioValue);
    viewModel.set("checkboxListValue", dummyData.checkboxListValue);
    viewModel.set("multipleSelectValue", dummyData.multipleSelectValue);
    viewModel.set("selectValue", dummyData.selectValue);

    //after you set the value, because the viewModel already bind with the component/value of the kendo widget on the HTML side the textbox/dropdown/checkbox will automatically updated
});
```

}

I also created a button on the html to trigger the getData function

```
<tr>
    <td><span data-role="button" data-bind="events:{click:getData}" />
         <h4>Click this to do ajax call </h4>
    </td>
</tr>
```

see this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aSEkI), click on the button and you'll see the data updated from (text value to new text value)

Comment: @trh178 This is what I was talking about. You can also avoid doing all the manual viewModel.set for each property if you bind your html elements to properties of an object in the viewmodel and set just that object with the data from your ajax call.

Comment: Perfect, just got through implementing this solution this morning. Working great.  Thanks for taking the time guys.